# STS/Eclipse showing Potential resource leak, why?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a service method which connects to MySQL and get data in `ResultSet` and in `finally` closed it's `PreparedStatement`, but STS showing a warning at return statement as

> Potential resource leak: 'resultSet' may not be closed at this
>   location

Method:

```
    public boolean checkData() {
        Connection dbConnection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        boolean status = false;
        try {
            dbConnection = icrud.getConnection();
            preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement("query on table");
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                status = resultSet.getBoolean("STATUS");
            }       
            return status;  //Potential resource leak warning shows here.
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception Occurred:: " , e);
        } finally {

            try {
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                    preparedStatement = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception Occured while Closing statement" , e);
            }

            try {
                if (dbConnection != null) {
                    dbConnection.close();
                    dbConnection = null;
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Exception Occured while closing connection" , e);
            }
        }
        return status;
    }
```

As per Doc,

> When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if
>   one exists, is also closed.

So I am closing `Statement` in finally though its showing warning. I have checked by closing result set in finally still warning doesn't go off.

Is it false positive? or Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because STS doesn't know about this rule. It just sees that you have created a Closeable, and haven't closed it explicitly. So it is a **potential** resource leak.

Comment: @JBNizet Ohh so it's just false positive warning, safe to ignore right? and whatever pattern for closing db connection and resources I am following is correct?

Comment: It's needlessly complex. Java has try-with-resources since Java 6 or 7. Use it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: And most importantly, don't catch Exception, and don't ignore it. This method should throw a SQLException, not catch it. Or at least throw another exception if a SQL Exception occurs.

Comment: @JBNizet In addition, in the light of connection and statement pools, closing the statement may not always really close the result set (usually in buggy pool implementations or pools that take shortcuts for 'performance').

Answer (score -2):

You are returning "status" without closing your connections. The "finally" clause isn't executed when you get to the return statement.

Comment: How? Can u explain?

Comment: dbConnection.close();
    preparedStatement.close();
    return status;

Comment: Please confirm that after return statement finally won't get executed..

Comment: I was wrong, it would execute. But maybe STS doesn't recognize that?